# PyTorch saves wrong weights for model (?)

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

TLDR: torch.save saves weights that differ a lot from cloning weights and saving them as .csv using numpy.

longer version:
currently I am developing a generative adversarial network for EEG-Data.

After a while I recognized that the lightning checkpoint models generate data that looks very different to what I see during training. The generated data during training looks promising. When using the saved network to generate data I am getting results that looks like results I usually see during earlier stages in training.

I started debugging and found out that when I save the model weights using numpy I'm getting very different weights compared to when saving with lightning checkpoints or using the torch.save function.

I think the difference in weights is responsible for the different results when generating data.

I posted about this a couple of days ago in the lightning.ai forum, you find some more information  [there](https://lightning.ai/forums/t/checkpointing-saves-wrong-model-weights-no-matter-if-lightning-or-bare-torch/3643).

To provide some code, I am using the following peace of code to compare the weights:

```
# Saving using numpy: 
filter_block1 = module.generator.block1.conv.weight.data.clone().flatten()
filter_block2 = module.generator.block2.conv.weight.data.clone().flatten()
filter_block3 = module.generator.block3.conv.weight.data.clone().flatten()
            
np.savetxt("/path/block1_conv2.csv", filter_block1.detach().cpu().numpy())
np.savetxt("/path/block2_conv2.csv", filter_block2.detach().cpu().numpy())
np.savetxt("/path/block3_conv2.csv", filter_block3.detach().cpu().numpy())

# Saving using torch: 
torch.save(module.generator.state_dict(), "/path/generator.pth")
torch.save(module.critic.state_dict(), "/path/critic.pth")
torch.save(module.state_dict(), "/path/model.pth")
```

If you want to see plots of the weights and the different results you can follow the link above. I also provide more information about the lightning training there because I thought its a lightning problem back then. However I just discovered that torch is also saving the wrong weights.

I can also provide the full training step in lightning if you need it.

It would be awesome if anyone could help me because I am now stuck for weeks and Id like to continue my research.

greetings
Samuel :)

There is more info found [here]((https://lightning.ai/forums/t/checkpointing-saves-wrong-model-weights-no-matter-if-lightning-or-bare-torch/3643) but I am always ready to post more code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I found this post: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-can-i-make-pytorch-save-all-the-weights-from-all-the-sub-layers-the-model-is-composed-of/178279

It turned out I had the same problem. My model is split into multiple blocks, these blocks are stored in a basic python list. The model can be trained as intended and shows the wanted results. When saving it's also saving something (probably some weights from a previous step) but not the current model state (weird behavior if you ask me).

To fix this the model blocks need to be stored in a  `nn.ModuleList`.